# Turn string[] into List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I have this strig[] :

```
string[] SkippedAreasArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"};
```

I want to turn this into :

```
 List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>  SkippedAreasArray  = ???
```

I haven't been working with this `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` data structure. So I have to questions how would my string array looked like if I turn it to `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` (how to define it?). And also - my logic is heavily depending on the indexes that are easily taken when I work with simple `string[]`. The idea to use `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` is that I may need to use values like `"A1"`, `"B1"`, `"B2"` and I understand `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>` is the better data structure to easily add those when I need but can I keep the correct indexing of the elements?

Comment: and what's your problem?

Comment: How would this turn to an int, string pair?  What is the integer part?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
string[] SkippedAreasArray = new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
"H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q"};
Dictionary<int,string> dictionary =
                 SkippedAreasArray.Select((r, i) => new { value = r, index = i })
                 .ToDictionary(t => t.index, t => t.value);
```

where `key` is the index and `value` is the alphabet.

OR

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list =
    SkippedAreasArray.Select((r, index) => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(index, r))
    .ToList()
```

;